# tsql query result in same column out of custom strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to fill a table parameter returned as a first table of a stored procedure.

I want this table to contain 'Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter3' in a column named 'Parameters'. All data is not from any database table it's just hard coded strings right in the stored proc.

I was wondering how to do that with a select query. I managed to do it on several columns but it'll be much more handy in the same one.

Edit to clarify a little (sorry for my english as it is obviously the problem):

Here's what I would like my SP to look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYSP]
(
@TopCount   INT = 10
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Users data' 'Orders data' AS 'TableNames'

    SELECT Top (@TopCount) User.Id AS 'User Id', User.EmailAddress AS 'User email address'  FROM User

    SELECT Top (@TopCount) Order.Id AS 'Order Id', Order.Number AS 'Order reference'  FROM Order
END
```

The first Select is wrong of course as it's why I'm here.

```
SELECT 'Users data' 'Orders data' AS 'TableNames'
```

Just trying to put strings in a result's column.

The expected output is a result table with one column named `TableNames` containing two rows:

```
TableNames
-----------
Users data
Orders data
```

And of course the two other tables with my users' data and my orders' data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could also provide some code examples and expected input/output to make the question more clear.

Comment: I think I speak for the group when I say. What?

Comment: The query was edited. The code turns out a little messy with the code tag but I think it's easier to understand despite that.

Comment: Ridiculous number of downvotes. (-5 at time of my comment).

Comment: @Zane If you are going to criticize someone's grammar, make sure yours is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a series of FROM-less SELECTs combined with a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 'Users data' AS TableNames
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Orders data';
```

Aliasing is needed only in the first SELECT.

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later version, there is an alternative to that – the [VALUES row constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  VALUES
    ('Users data'),
    ('Orders data')
) AS v (TableNames);
```